# Pop to root view in an unwind segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, pushviewcontroller

My view controller sequence is as follows:

A -> (push) -> B -> (modal) -> C

I return from C to B using an unwind segue and it works.

I would like however to return directly from C to A.

In that unwind segue which is located in B, I try to pop to root view:

```
-(IBAction)unwindToBfromC:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and I get this error:

```
Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.
```

When I however execute:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

in B in a button action I return to A no problem. What's wrong?

Comment: I found a nice and elegant solution here: link

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a link there...

Comment: What a silly mistake. The link's here: http://chrisrisner.com/Unwinding-with-iOS-and-Storyboards

Comment: follow the step...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Answer (score 0):

Since C is in the modal, there is nothing to pop to. So dismiss it instead.

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: When I dismiss C this way I will only go back to B.

Comment: My bad! What if you use `[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];`? It's a bit dirty though.

Comment: Then nothing happens because it is a modal, which is a root view to itself. I found a nice solution and posted a link to it in a comment to my answer.